# Fetch contacts from google contact api java

Tags: java, google-contacts-api, parseexception

I am able to get access token for google contact API. Now I am not able to figure out how to use that token to fetch contacts. The method available in Google Contact API documentation does not involve access token. Also I don't know how to call that method  in Java.

If Anyone can help me with that, it will be highly appreciable.

```
ContactsService service = new ContactsService("Test");
service.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
URL feedUrl = new URL("google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
ContactFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
System.out.println(resultFeed.getTitle().getPlainText());
```

This is how I am trying to fetch contacts but I am getting:

`com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Feature: xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code?

Comment: Now It is mentioned in my Question @PhilippFlenker